# The title postgraduate researcher

Tags: cv, united-kingdom, titles, social-media

I have seen the title postgraduate researcher in a couple of peoples Linkedin profiles for roles in the UK. The people listed only had masters degree before showing. What is this position formally, is it just someone who has not completed a PhD? Or are these official positions in subjects like astronomy?

Comment: It might be a title granted by some institution, but it might also, perhaps, be intended as nothing more than a descriptive phrase.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, postgraduate research would, equally, be known as both Ph.D. and post-doctoral programs. Graduate studies do cover M.Sc. programs, there. Therefore, whatever after that would be named as postgraduate. So, one might assert that a postgraduate researcher could be either a Ph.D. candidate or a post-doctoral fellow.

Of course, theses definitions are highly flexible and even interchangeable among different universities, even in UK.

Comment: In the UK, as far as I understand it, grad students are called *postgraduate students* (the logic is simple: you were undergraduate, then you graduated, now you are a postgraduate student). Postdocs are postdocs, often called research fellows, or the likes of that. I'd guess that a postgraduate researcher, in the UK context, is someone who a researcher (or a research assistant) with only a bachelor or a masters degree.